# row value is column name of 2nd table, need result from 2nd table

Tags: mysql

I need to create a view from 2 tables

Table 1

```
  app_id    cat_id  approver    level   proj_id

  1            1    pm_id         1       731
  1            2    dm_id         2       843
  1            3    dm_id         1       859
  2            4    bo_id         1       859
```

table 2

```
  proj_id   pm_id   dm_id   bo_id

  731       100102  100034  100121
  843       123121  145721  104321
  859       112312  132434  132435
```

My approver id is in table 2 and the table 1 denotes who is the approver for the project based on the level. I want to create a view for the list of approval pending with the pm, dm and bo.

e.g. result table

```
app_id  cat_id  approver

1         1      100102
1         2      145721
1         3      132434
2         4      132435
```

Comment: Inner join http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: `Select table1.app_id, table1.cat_id, table2.pm_id as approver from table1 inner join table2 on table1.proj_id = table2.proj_id` Now try to learn a bit more by your self, read some tutorail on line do some research.

Comment: here is some stack overflow documentation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/2736/joins#t=201705310934419709604

Comment: Sorry @DragandDrop, if that could have been the case I wouldn't have asked on this forum. I just don't want pm_id, I need the column value from the table 2 where the column name value from table 1. Please check the result table

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` to join two tables together, then use `case when` to get approver.

```
select
    table1.app_id,
    table1.cat_id,
    case when table1.approver = 'pm_id' then table2.pm_id
         when table1.approver = 'dm_id' then table2.dm_id
         when table1.approver = 'bo_id' then table2.bo_id
    end as approver
from table1
left join table2 on table1.proj_id = table2.proj_id
```

See [***demo***](http://rextester.com/JZAL52564) in rextester.

***Edit***:

If you have dynamic approver, try this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  CONCAT('CASE', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      CONCAT(' WHEN table1.approver = ''',
      approver,
      ''' THEN table2.', approver) SEPARATOR ' '), ' END AS approver'
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT table1.app_id, table1.cat_id, ', @sql, ' FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.proj_id = table2.proj_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Also have a [***demo***](http://rextester.com/QURI18400) in Rextester.

Create ***VIEW***:

```
create view view1
as
select
    table1.app_id,
    table1.cat_id,
    case when table1.approver = 'pm_id' then table2.pm_id
         when table1.approver = 'dm_id' then table2.dm_id
         when table1.approver = 'bo_id' then table2.bo_id
    end as approver
from table1
left join table2 on table1.proj_id = table2.proj_id
```

Comment: What if there are 10 different approver in table 1, should I be writing 10 different case?

Comment: In my opinion, YES. However, if you do exactly have more than 10 different approver, then in `table2` should have corresponded columns, is this your table's design? If yes, dynamic sql will solve too many different cases. @user2483712

Comment: Yes. you are correct there are at-least 6 levels im_id, pm_id, dm_id, bo_id, hr_id and am_id for now. They can increase these. I need the column value from the table 2 where the column name value from table 1. Please check the result table

Comment: @user2483712 Check the ***Edit*** part.

Comment: Thank you so much for the option, one question can I do this in single query as I need to create this as a view (not a store procedure)?

Comment: @user2483712 Single query, I've given you, 10 different cases.

Comment: even after spending time for 4 hrs I could create a view, I am sorry but I need help

Comment: See create ***VIEW***.